# React Native - text gets truncated too much

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following component

```
const InputLabel => (props: InputLabelProps) {
    return (
        <Animated.View
            style={[
                StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
                {
                    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                },
            ]}
        >
            <Animated.Text
                onLayout={onLayoutAnimatedText}
                numberOfLines={1}
                ellipsizeMode="tail"
                textBreakStrategy={'highQuality'}
                style={[
                    animatedLabelContainerStyle,
                    {
                        textAlign: 'right',
                        fontSize: fontSize,
                        color: labelColor,
                        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                    },
                ]}
            >
                {label}
            </Animated.Text>
        </Animated.View>
    );
}
```

When I reference it from another component and I set the width of wrapper component below a certain value the text is truncated too much leaving a big gap.

```
<View style={{ width: '40%', height: 50, borderWidth: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
                <InputLabel
                    fontSize={16}
                    hasOutline={false}
                    label={'label 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'}
                    // labelAnimatedValue={labelAnimation}
                    labelColor={'black'}
                    labelLayout={labelLayout}
                    OffsetY={2} //container borderWidth
                    placeholderColor={'red'}
                    showPlaceholder={false}
                    onLayoutAnimatedText={handleLayoutAnimatedText}
                />
</View>
```

The code above with width at 40% produces the below
[Width at 40%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLdL1.png)

When I set width at 50% or greater the text is truncated how I want it
[Width at 50%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Vas.png)

What I want is:

yellow background to stretch to the end of the red container at all width

Please note if the label length is not long enough to be truncated the yellow color should only wrap text and not stretch to end of red container

Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@danro/inputlabel

Expected result with short label [image: Expected short label]

Expected result with long label [image: Expected long label]

Comment: Add a snack repro so that we can check what is going wrong!

Comment: I created the snack repo but it's not replicated on snack. It displays exactly how it I expect it to be displayed. Any idea why? Snack:  https://snack.expo.dev/@danro/inputlabel

Comment: Are you using exact same code? and the same parent styles? In most cases, the culprit is `align-items` or `align-self` property.

Comment: I am using the same code. I was shocked when I saw it work on snack. I copied the snack code and paste in my editor but it didn't change the behavior on my local

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use it with `flex` ? I would try to give `flex:1`.

Comment: flex: 1 - did not resolve issue

Answer (score 0):

You can either add flex: 1 or width:"100%" to the text ..

---

**edit**:

in **InputLabel.tsx**
remove flexDirection: row and alignItems: center from Animated View

Comment: I have edited the question to add snack. There are no padding.  On the snack it displays as expected but not on emulator. Any idea why?

Comment: I just checked snack and I edited my answer .. Now, it works

Comment: The suggested approach causes the short label to break. Please see edit to original question where I had expected results for various length labels

Comment: check this https://snack.expo.dev/@salwa_soliman/inputlabel .. you can determine whether it's short or not dynamically througn calculating the number of letters in your label

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Text
     {...props}
     numberOfLines={1}
     ellipsizeMode={'head' | 'middle' | 'tail' | 'clip'}
     onPress={props.onPress}
     style={style.textStyle}>
     Some long long long text
  </Text>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).